# Multiple Instances of Ninject with Owin

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ninject, owin

So I have a Visual Studio solution with a number of projects. One project (`Host`) has a startup method like so:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace DMSServer.Host
{
  public class Startup
  {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
      app.UseService1();
      app.UseService2();
    }
  }
}
```

And two seperate `WebApi` projects, one that contains the `UseService1` method and the other that has the `UseService2`. In these `UseServiceX` methods, I am setting up my Ninject Kernel and Ninject WebApi using Owin middleware.

```
//In project1
public static IAppBuilder UseService1(this IAppBuilder app)
{
  app.UseNinjectMiddleware(NinjectConfig.CreateKernel);
  var httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
  app.UseNinjectWebApi(httpConfig)
  return app;
}
===========================================================
//In project2
public static IAppBuilder UseService2(this IAppBuilder app)
{
  app.UseNinjectMiddleware(NinjectConfig.CreateKernel);
  var httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
  app.UseNinjectWebApi(httpConfig)
  return app;
}
```

My issue arises whenever I run the application, because I am calling the UseNinjectMiddleware on the same `app` twice. Is there any way around this?

[image]

Comment: Yes, don't do that.  You should never configure DI in your services.  It should always be in the Composition root.  This violates a core principle of dependency injection, and why you are having problems.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I have a NinjectConfig in each one of the projects, should I consolidate them into one so I only end up calling the `app.UseNinjectMiddleware` once?

Comment: I would suggest doing your configuration in classes derived from NinjectModule, you can then use kernel.Load() to automatically load the ninject modules, this way you can leave your configuration in the individual projects, but only perform your kernel creation and loading once.